# Assign ID's to Polylines in Android Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, data-structures, google-polyline

I want to assign ID's to multiple Polylines that I am making based on coordinates. The reason is so that I can refer to a particular Polyline when needed.

Here is my sample code for making Polylines.

```
 PolylineOptions lineoption = new PolylineOptions().add(new LatLng(a1, b1))
                .add(new LatLng(a2, b2))
                .color(Color.GREEN);
        line = mMap.addPolyline(lineoption);
```

What data-structure would be best for storing multiple Polylines with their respective ID's?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Take ArrayList to save the coordinates you can directly give that arraylist to polyoptions for drawing polyline on map. If you want index of the polyline then take one  HashMap integer holds index for polyline.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. I have ussed an ArrayList to store my Polylines now, but is there any other way then identifying the polylines through this index method by a HashMap? I mean can't I add any text or something to an individual polyline?